# How to set "max_table_count_in_statement" to 8192 in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

I need to change limitation in SAP HANA.
I run first the below sql to check if "MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_TABLES_IN_STATEMENT" is set:

```
SELECT * FROM M_SYSTEM_LIMITS;
```

Found no MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_TABLES_IN_STATEMENT. According to documentation, this means that MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_TABLES_IN_STATEMENT=0

How can i set the value now to 8192?
I have tried the following sql:

```
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('nameserver.ini', 'SYSTEM') SET ('sql', 'max_table_count_in_statement') = '8192' WITH RECONFIGURE;
```

The error that i get is following:

```
Configuration parameters for nameserver.ini can only be altered from SYSTEMDB SQLSTATE: HY000
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

1. Login as systemdb

   ```
   hdbsql -n localhost -i 01 -u system -p XXXXXXX -d SYSTEMDB
   ```
2. Run the sql to update:

   ```
   ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('nameserver.ini', 'SYSTEM') SET ('sql'
      , 'max_table_count_in_statement') = '8192' WITH RECONFIGURE;
   ```
3. Validate the change:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM M_SYSTEM_LIMITS;
   ```
4. Expected result:
   `"DATABASE","MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_TABLES_IN_STATEMENT","8192","INTEGER","","This restriction shows the maximum number of tables including repeated occurrences in a statement. For example, given a table T1 and a view V1, the number is three for a query \"SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) FROM T1, T1\" because T1 appears three times. If the definition of V1 includes T1 four times, the number for another query \"SELECT * FROM T1, V1\" is five (one for T1 and four for V1)."`